# QT5 Text rendering issue

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qt5

I have cross compiled QT5 on a MIPS based platform. 
Whenever I run application including sample apps, (Which contains text), first it draws the text and later paints the area of text with "rectangle" fill of Text Color.

So finally I see a black rectangle all the places where text is displayed. If i change the text color, the color of rectangle also changes. Has anybody faced this issue? Any suggestions?

Even when I run qtwebkit, I see that URL part, the text in any HTML page is painted with rectangle fills.

Thanks

Comment: Since this is more of Qt5 issues (the Alpha release), i would Like to close this. This question would have been more relevant in Qt-Development forum than here (as it was a problem in Alpha release)

Comment: Is this still a problem? Qt 5 stable is out now...

Comment: Now its not a problem and hence I wanted to Close the question. Please see my comment on the question.